# How many counts does a mouse need to report to move the windows cursor for 1 pixel exactly?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, mouse-cursor

How many counts does a mouse need to report to move the windows cursor for 1 pixel exactly?
Is it 1 to 1 perfect match? So that if I have a 400 DPI mouse and move it for 1 inch, the cursor would move 400 pixels across the windows desktop?
If it's not 1:1 then what's the ratio?
At the default `cursor speed` `pointer speed` value `10/20` `6/11` of course.

Comment: Actually I've been testing/measuring it with my mouse, but it's not very accurate when moving my mouse for 1 inch lol. Anyway the result seems to be close to 1:1. Would be nice if someone could confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct :
A mouse set at 400 DPI will move the cursor 400 pixels
per inch that the mouse travels.

CPI (counts per inch) and DPI (dots per inch) are terms used interchangeably to measure mouse sensitivity. Mouse manufacturers often use these terms interchangeably.

DPI is the number of pixels that can fit into one inch on your
mouse sensor's surface.
The higher the DPI, the quicker the cursor moves.

The behavior of cursor/pointer speed and other settings depend on the
mouse software and on the operating system.
This is a vast subject, too vast to discuss here.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm asking for windows 10 specifically. And by report I mean the report that OS gets from driver, so everything should be within OS only right? So... your answer means that by default the windows 10 OS should move the cursor x pixels when receiving x counts from mouse driver, no more no less?

Comment: Yes, that's the case if Windows and the driver do not employ other algorithms such as acceleration, movement curves etc.

Answer (score 2):

Given that modern hardware uses USB, not PS/2, I'm going to answer this solely from a USB perspective. Answering for ancient hardware just does not make sense.

USB uses pollingrate.
At each poll, it gets an image of what is under the sensor.
At the next poll, it will compare the new image with the previously taken image.

If they are different, the distance is calculated, and the mouse travels.

Its not a matter of, how many pixels does it take over time, but how fast the polling rate.

For that reason, there is no way to say exactly when 1 pixel was traversed.

Do note, that the lower the DPI is, the harder it is for the sensor to know if the mouse has moved, but rather than it moving 1 pixel at a slow move, it may move 2 or more instead.

Also note, if the polling rate is low, the mouse will appear laggy, as it skips many pixels with just one quick mouse move.

Lastly, in Windows, you have the option "precise mouse movement" which enables mouse accelleration.
Also, gaming mice often have this in their drivers, which usually is called mouse accelleration.

Without mouse accelleration, the moving the mouse should translate 1:1 to the mouse cursor if the polling and DPI are high enough, but with mouse accelleration on, this is no longer the case.

Comment: Yes. I need to say that there's no mouse accelleration taken into consideration. So to be clear, if the OS get x counts from mouse driver, it should move the cursor x pixels, no more no less, right? And this is hardware irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, its a 1:1, but the reason a mouse can be inaccurate is because of a low DPI simply not seeing enough pixels under the sensor to accurately destinguish for a 1px movement.

Comment: I know that gaming mice can have adjustable DPI. So my guess is that the sensor would report in inches (or other length unit), and then the mouse firmware would translate those inches to dots. Which means, as long as the sensor is good, the mouse will be accurate even if it's on a low DPI say 400? Because the sensor is working at a much higher resolution and then gets scaled down, I suppose?

Comment: The image is not scaled down, but because you travel the same distance, but more pixels are measured, the speed increases when the DPI increases. Lets say, you take a photo in 3 mega pixels, and one in 8 mega pixels. Its the same photo, taken on the same location of the same suspect. The suspect is a person. If you take the X,Y coordinates of the left eye and the one of the right eye, in the 3 MP version, the distance is a lot less than in the 8MP version.